# Python: Writing to file writes data from previous running of code

Tags: python

In my code I have 2 seperate commands writing 2 different lists to a file:

```
    f = open("output2D All.txt", "w")
for item in Plist:
    f.write(str(item) + ", ")
f.write("\n\n")
for item in R2_list:
    f.write(str(item) + ", ")
f.close

g = open("output2D Log.txt", "w")
for item in Plist2:
    g.write(str(item) + ", ")
g.write("\n\n")
for item in R2_list2:
    g.write(str(item) + ", ")

g.close
```

I realise this might not be the most efficient way of doing this, however my problem comes with the second command (ie the g). It is writing data from the previous running of the code? For example I run the whole code for the first time, and the first write command writes the data fine, however the "output2D Log.txt" file remains empty. Then I run the code a second time, and the "output2D" file is overwritten as expected, however the "output2D Log.txt" writes the data from the previous running.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`f.close` and `g.close` don't do anything. They're just function references, not calls -- meaning you never actually close the file.

Change your lines to `f.close()` and `g.close()`.